# How to make images of different sizes all fit to be the same size?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on coding my graphic design portfolio website, and I'm working on creating a clickable gallery where I place images of my work in a grid. I'm able to set up the grid okay, but my pictures are all still different sizes and its messing up the grid.
the grid I'm working on looks like this:

[image]

It is my first time posting, I'm sorry if this isn't explained well.

```css
.gallery {
    width: 700px;
    display: flex;
}
.gallery div {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex: none;
}
.gallery div img {
    width: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>
    <span><img src="images/cafe ole final-01 copy.png" alt="Cafe Ole"></span>
    <span><img src="images/Nintendo logo redesign-03.png" alt="Nintendo redesign"></span>
    <span><img src="images/shibuya airport logo branding-02 copy.png" alt="Shibuya Airport"></span>
    <span><img src="images/rocket wireless.png" alt="rocket wireless"></span>
    <span><img src="images/transfriend logo 2-02.png" alt="transfriend"></span>
    <span><img src="images/Spotify UI Design.png" alt="Spotify UI Design"></span>
    <span><img src="images/bapeshoead2-01 copy.png" alt=""></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you like the pictures to do differently?  You could make it so that they all have a max-height and are cropped to only show the top or middle sections.

Comment: Do you want all images to be the same width and height?

Comment: The grid is perfectly fine -- 3 across in each row.  You just have to decide what to do when a picture doesn't fill the box.

Comment: try this  `img{object-fit: cover;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.  Instead of an `<img>` tag just set the `background-image` style on each element and then you have full control in CSS of how it appears.  If you use `background-size: cover;` it is cropped to a square in the middle of each image.  If you instead use `background-size: contain;` you see the full image but it might have some empty space around it.  It just depends what you want to do.

```css
.gallery {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
}
.gallery div {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: none;
}
.gallery .thumbnail {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size: contain;*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/50/150/150');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/51/100/150');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/52/150/100');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/53/200/150');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/54/100/150');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/55/100/150');"></span>
    <span class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/56/100/150');"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For images of various sizes to display as the same size, the images will need to be either stretched or cropped.

If you give the images the same width and height, the images will distort their intrinsic aspect ratio to fill the given dimensions. You can use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS property to declare `cover` and the images will maintain the intrinsic aspect ratio but cut off the overflowing edges to center itself and fill the given dimensions.

In addition to what others have already answered with, I wanted to trim and alter your code

- remove the unneeded `div` and `span` elements and Flexbox properties
- use [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) for simplicity and [`1fr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex_value) for the grid columns to be equal width
- use `max-width` instead of `width` so the grid will be responsive in narrower viewports
- `grid-gap` has been replaced by (and is now an alias for) [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)
- use `width: 100%` on the images so they'll fill the cell width and be responsive
- use [`aspect-ratio: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) so the images have equal width and height
- use [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) instead of [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) because we're not working with background images

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5XkVC.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/V98jS.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/iU8gS.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/DAhRX.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/xIOau.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/9WWJB.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/7D7AB.png">
</div>
```

You likely don't want the images to get clipped or distorted. Another option is to place images with similar sizes in the same row and declare [`align-self: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) (instead of `aspect-ratio: 1` and `object-fit: cover`). Organizing the images this way will minimize the distortion.

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5XkVC.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/V98jS.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/DAhRX.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/iU8gS.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/xIOau.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/9WWJB.png">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/7D7AB.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your pictures are same sizes and it should not messing up the grid then you should try them with proper height and width and still if you seeing same issue try object-fit property.

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

I wrapped each `img` with `a` tag for make them clickable. And `target="_blank"` is for the new tab but you can remove all if u want

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 700px;
}

.gallery a img{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Cafe Ole"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x300" alt="Nintendo redesign"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" alt="Shibuya Airport"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="rocket wireless"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200" alt="transfriend"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="Spotify UI Design"></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" alt=""></a>
</div>
```